# Issue with div display, css @media vs javascript

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

For my first responsive design I use css @media with display: none; or display:table-cell to show or hide sidebars. This works fine, I need the display:table-cell for a three divs layout.

CSS example:

```
#div_right { display: table-cell; }
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) { #div_right {display: none; } }
```

JS is standard ToogleDisplay function (with e.style.display = "table-cell"; in place of e.style.display = "block"; )

On small windows/screen the sidebars are hidden, but a new div with 2 options to display these 2 same navigation sidebars appears: clicking on a link with embedded javascript, allows to toogle display of a  sidebar div. It also works fine.

The problem comes when I show then hide the sidebars by clicking on the JS links (on small windows), and then resize the window to a larger width: the sidebars are not displayed this time!

Is there a @media condition to specify "on larger width than xxx" do force display:table-cell; ?

I don't want to use jQuery, and a solution with CSS would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using jquery to $.('el').css("display","none") or .hide() the elements? If so jquery will add the style as an inline-style - hence overwriting your media query. 
You can try to add !important to your CSS code (the media query) and it might work.
See: http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2013/05/css/using-important-in-your-media-queries

Also please note the follow rule of thumb:
CSS style is applied in the following hierachy/priority:
!important is always highest priority
The closer styles to your elements will override styles defined before:
inline styles are higher priority
CSS styles are lowest priority

Please check: developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.web.appprogramming/html/guide/w3c_guide/dom_guide/html_priorities_css.htm

Also you might want to use not only min-width, but rather a range like:
@media screen (min-width: xxx) and (max-width: yyy){ }

Check out some standard templates from: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: I dont think he is using jquery, as he said at the bottom of his question that he didnt want to us it, but if he is, that would be it. But using `!important` is not good practice, as it overrides all other CSS. it would be better to use JQuery.

Comment: Oh I just read the "JS is standard ToogleDisplay function (with e.style.display = "table-cell"; in place of e.style.display = "block"; )" line as if he might be in a JS/Jquery situation. I agree with letting go of !important and editing the inline-style instead.

Comment: No jQuery, but  !important seems to do the job !!! First time I find some use for it. Thanks very much.

Comment: You're welcome buddy. Consider Imagine Studios answer tho. He is right about trying to avoid !important as often as you can, thus !important is faster to implement "on the go"...

Comment: @S.E. If using !important works, it means you have a overriding style somewhere. you should inspect the element, and find out where it is instead of using !important

Answer (score 1):

Just use `min-width` instead of `max-width`:

```
#div_right { display: table-cell; }
@media screen and (min-width: xxx) { #div_right {display: none; } }
```

Very simple, tells the browser that these rules are to be used if the browser is larger then `xxx`.
If you want to know everything about @media queries, check out the [Mozilla Docs On It](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).
Could be very helpful to you.

## To see it in action, see this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/f63wyo4n/2/)

[EDIT]
As noted in the other answer, if you are using jquery, it will override the @media rule.
The correct way to do this, not using `!important` is to use jquery:
In your js:

```
$(".menu").show().css("display","block");
```

This JS shows it as `display:block;`

Comment: I'm trying this with different break points, different order, still the same problem. I'll look at the link.